# Exchange subpartition failed because of VPD even after grant exempt policy

Tags: oracle, exception, partitioning, vpd

I have a process that execute `EXCHANGE SUBPARTITION` statement.

Acoording to the fact that all the tables in the schema have a `VPD POLICY` protection,

we have a stored procedure that grant `EXEMPT ACCESS POLICY` to the user just before the action and revoke it just after the action.

Normally it's working perfect, but sometimes, we still get this exception:

> ORA-14136: ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE restricted by fine-grained security

It occours even after we gave the grant.

Example:

The exchange subpartition code:

```
-- exchange subpartition statement
--ALTER TABLE DWH.FACT_AMS EXCHANGE SUBPARTITION P07_2017_ALL_AUDIT WITH TABLE DWH.MNG_ALL_CURRENT_KPIS

V_EXEC_I :=Q_CUR.SQL_QUERY;                                                      

--insert to log the exchage partition step
LOG_WRITER_INS(V_EXEC_I,V_ERROR_MSG,V_COMMENT_MSG,V_MASTER,C_PROCESS_NAME,C_PID);

-- execute exchange subpartition statement
DBA_MAINT.SF_GRANT_EXCEMPT(1);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_EXEC_I;
DBA_MAINT.SF_GRANT_EXCEMPT(0);
```

The sf_grant_excempt procedure:

```
create or replace
procedure           SF_GRANT_EXCEMPT(grant_opt in number)
is

v_cnt number := -1;

begin

if grant_opt = 1 then
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT EXEMPT ACCESS POLICY TO dwh';
ELSIF GRANT_OPT = 0 THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'REVOKE EXEMPT ACCESS POLICY from dwh';
END IF;

END SF_GRANT_EXCEMPT;
```

It can happend with different tables (this is a dynamic process), but the tables which involved in the statement are always of the same owner (which is always dwh), the code of the `EXCHANGE SUBPARTITION` is of package of the same user also (Dwh), and the exception we got is not comming from the SF_GRANT_EXCEMPT procedure. So the grant is working...

Comment: Could the exchange code be being called twice simultaneously, maybe independently for different subpartitions - so the grant/revoke happens for both calls but overlap? i.e. a race condition between two calls?

Comment: Something that I forgot to mention...  more then one invoke of the exchange code is impossible..  This code can't run simultaneously.